# how to create buddypress shortcodes?

Tags: buddypress

I have code to get value of buddypress xtended profile :

```
function get_nickname() {
   echo 'field: ' . xprofile_get_field_data( 3, bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'comma' );
}
add_action( 'bp_ready', 'get_nickname' );
```

i need to make a shortcode return nickname or render nickname.

honestly i tried read documentation, but i still dont understand to do that.

how to create buddypress shortcodes?

Answer (score 0):

can you just add_shortcode?

```
add_shortcode ('use-this', 'get_nickname');
```

now in your code call [use-this]

of course change 'use-this' to whatever you want in both places if you want to change it.